# Data in dataframe is squeezed. How can I fix that?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I was practicing Python and stuck with this issue. Data from my csv file is displayed in an odd way. Can you help?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q1Fie.png)

Comment: Could you please share a screenshot of the raw data?

Comment: @Alfonso_MA not a screenshot, but text of the actual data

Comment: import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df_exams=pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\alnur\Downloads\StudentsPerformance.csv")

df_exams.head(5)


Here is the file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EzC_nn3M_okrjKuZbgvDXF_N27YuUBGg/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.